# How to separate odd subcategories in cplex

Tags: union, cplex

I have obtained the set of odd nodes of a graph and generated all its subsets. Now I want to separate those subsets whose size is odd.
I would appreciate it if you could help me :)

There are two solutions in my mind, the first one works correctly, but I have to add a null collection. And the second solution, I don't know how to write it correctly

```
range SS=1..ftoi(2^n_odd-1);
{int} Sub_odd[s in SS] = {item(odd_nodes,i-1) | i in 1..n_odd : (s div ftoi(2^(i-1))) mod 2 == 1};
```

1. {int} Sub_odd_odd[s in SS] = card(Sub_odd[s]) mod 2 ==1? Sub_odd[s]:{} ;
2. {int} Sub_odd_odd = union(Sub_odd[s] | s in SS : card(Sub_odd[s]) mod 2 ==1 );

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the [powerset example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/powerset.mod) you can filter and keep the odd instances:

```
{string} s={"A","B","C","D"};
range r=1.. ftoi(pow(2,card(s)));
{string} s2 [k in r] = {i | i in s: ((k div (ftoi(pow(2,(ord(s,i))))) mod 2) == 1)};
    
{int} subr={i| i in r:card(s2[i]) mod 2==1};

{string} subs2[i in subr]=s2[i];  

execute
{
     writeln(s2);
     writeln(subs2);
}
```

which gives

```
 [{"A"} {"B"} {"A" "B"} {"C"} {"A" "C"} {"B" "C"} {"A" "B" "C"} {"D"} {"A" "D"}
         {"B" "D"} {"A" "B" "D"} {"C" "D"} {"A" "C" "D"} {"B" "C" "D"} {"A"
         "B" "C" "D"} {}]
 [{"A"} {"B"} {"C"} {"A" "B" "C"} {"D"} {"A" "B" "D"} {"A" "C" "D"} {"B" "C"
         "D"}]
```